# What do virtual network adapter (for guest) do on Host computer?

Tags: networking, vmware, virtualization

What do 'VMware Network Adapter VMnet1's represent in my Network Connections? And how is the Guest still able to connect to the internet even after I disable it?

[image]

I might me missing some concepts of networking itself so from what I understand if I disble the virtual adapter created for the Guest it should sever all connections to it. Then how come it can still access the internet (from Host)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guest is setup to use NAT which means its traffic goes to a background vmware process that pipes the traffic through your host's network stack (i.e. using your host's IP, etc.). If you want to disable that, you'll have to disable the network adapter in the vm's configuration.

The virtual network adapter you see in your host is for host-to-guest-only networking. Your guests can be configured to connects to each other in a virtual LAN (nothing to do with VLAN). The virtual network adapter is there for your host to participate in these virtual LANs. If you didn't setup your guests to talk to your host directly, then that adapter simply does nothing. (I.e. is not used to pipe the NAT traffic.)